# splitting up values from database in html table

Tags: javascript, html, sql, node.js, ejs

I am putting items into my html table which are coming from my database. these items are being stored in there from each order placed on my website. so if someone orders two items, I basically want to show, this:

```
| NAME  | $    | QTY |
|:----  |:----:|   -:|
| item1 | 2.25 |   1 |
|:----  |:----:|   -:|
| item2 | 4.91 |   2 |
```

but right now, I am getting

```
| NAME  | $    | QTY |
|:----  |:----:|   -:|
| item1item2 | 2.25 |   1 |
```

here's my front end code. I don't think backend code is necessary for this, but correct me if im wrong!

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <% if(data.length){ 
                    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
              <h4>ORDER DETAILS FOR ORDER NUMBER <%= data[i].ORDERNUM %></h4>
              <% }
            }else{ %>
                <% } %>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ORDER NUMBER</th>
                  <th>ITEM NAME</th>
                  <th>PRICE</th>
                  <th>QTY</th>
                  <th>EACH CASE</th>
                  <th>SIZE</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <% if(data.length){ 
                    for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= data[i].ORDERNUM %></td>
                  <td><%= data[i].ITEMNAME %></td>
                  <td><%= data[i].ITEMPRICE %></td>
                  <td><%= data[i].QTY %></td>
                  <td><%= data[i].EACH_CASE %></td>

                  <script>
                      if ("<%= data[i].SIZE %>" == "undefined") {
                          document.write("<td>N/A</td>")
                      } else {
                          document.write("<td><%= data[i].SIZE %></td>")
                      }
                  </script>
              </tbody>
              <% }
            }else{ %>
                <% } %>
            </table>
```

not sure how to fix.. thanks for the help!

Comment: You only need one loop, place your head row outside the for loop, then loop the db items inside the for loop creating your tr, then td items, **remember to close the tr that handles the BD items inside the loop**. Once looped wrap up the tbody and table again outside your loop. You can always inspect your code in developer tools to see how your table structure is being produced for more troubleshooting.